# angular resolve dependency on promise

Tags: angularjs

So here's my general problem, I have a factory which needs to make an ajax call to get its value. I want to inject this factory, but only after the ajax call has been resolved, meaning, when it's injected, I want the value to already be there. Is this possible? Let me give you some context so you can maybe give me a better option.

I have a UserFactory.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.factory('UserFactory',[

    function(){
      //ajax call to get the user object  
      //dont allow injection until user has arrived
   }
]);


var home = angular.module('home',[]);
home.controller('UserInfoController',[
   'UserFactory',//I don't want this resolved until the ajax call has completed
    function(User){
      //bind user data to the view
    }
]);
```

Is this possible? Or am I going about this wrong? I want to be able to access the user's information without having to use promises every time, just in case it's not already there.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are concerned about using promises. How about just checking to see if user is there, if it is do nothing, if not then use the factory promise to set it.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is set up your factory so that it remembers the user data.

Something like this

```
app.factory('userFactory', function ($http){
    return {
        getUser: function(){
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: ''
            });
        },
        currentUser: {}
    };
});
```

So then in your controller, check to see if there is anything in currentUser. If not make the getUser call and store it into currentUser. Since the factory is a singleton the userdata will always exists inside this factory and you can inject it anywhere you need it.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/4m6gmsw2/

If you still need the user data to be there before injecting it you can take a look at using resolve: https://thinkster.io/egghead/resolve/

Answer (score 0):

In the state router, there is resolve property for each state.

```
.state({
  name: 'myState',
  resolve: {
    user: function(myService) {
      return myService.asyncGet();
    }
  }
```

Then in your controller:

```
.controller('myController', function(user) {
  $scope.myData = user.data;  //no messy promises
});
```